# Get Angular JS,Require JS & Framework 7 to work-together

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a seed application using Angular JS,RequireJS & Framework 7. I have so far created the following folder structure.

My main folder looks like below:

[image]

and my scripts folder looks like this :

[image]

and my libraries are :

[image]

I was able to the view -> controller flow working properly. But when I try to inject a service object to the controller I get the following error.

[image]

I am sure I must be missing something. I have given my code below:

require-main:

```
(function() {
require.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts",    

    // alias libraries paths
    paths: {
        'angular': '../libs/angular',
        'angular-route': '../libs/angular-route',
        'angular-animate':'../libs/angular-animate',
        'angularAMD': '../libs/angularAMD.min',
        'Framework7':'../libs/framework7',
        'UserController':'controller/UserCtrl',
        'WebCallManager':'services/WebCallManager'
    },

    // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
    shim: { 
        'angularAMD': ['angular'],
        'angular-route': ['angular'],
        'angular-animate':['angular'],
        'Framework7':{exports: 'Framework7'}
    },

    //kick start application
    deps: ['app']
});

require(['Framework7'], function(Framework7) {

     f7 = new Framework7({
        modalTitle: 'Seed App',
        swipePanel: 'left',
        animateNavBackIcon: true
    });

    return {
        f7: f7
    };
});

 })();
```

app.js :

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route','angular-animate'], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/", angularAMD.route({ templateUrl: '../pages/login.html',controller: 'UserController'}));
    $routeProvider.when("/login", angularAMD.route({ templateUrl: '../pages/home.html', controller: 'UserController'}));
});
angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
return app;
});
```

UserController :

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
app.register.controller('UserController', function ($scope,$location,webcallService) {

    $scope.loginUser = function(){
        console.log("Login User Called...");
        $location.path('/login').replace();
        console.log("View Navigated...");
    };


    $scope.slidePanel = function(){
         f7.openPanel('left');
    };


    $scope.doWebCall = function(){
        console.log("Doing the Web Call...");
        webcallService.sendGetRequest();
    };
});
 });
```

WebCallManager.js (Service)

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
app.service('webcallService', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.sendGetRequest = function() {
        console.log("Sending HTTP Get Request");
    }

    self.sendPostRequest = function() {
        console.log("Sending HTTP Post Request");
    }
});
 });
```

And my pages :

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="slide-animation page-content" ng-view ></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
<div class="content-block login-input-content">
<div class="store-data list-block">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="login-name" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <a class="multi-language" href="#"><i class="icon ios7-world-outline"></i><span>english</span></a>
     </div>    
     </div>

     <div class="content-block login-btn-content">
     <button ng-click="loginUser()" class="button button-big button-submit login-submit">Login</button>
     </div>
```

Home.html:

```
<div>
 <h3>Welcome to Mobility In Angular-JS</h3>
<div class="content-block login-btn-content">
    <button ng-click="doWebCall()" class="button button-big button-submit login-submit">Send Get</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button ng-click="doWebCall()" class="button button-big button-submit login-submit">Send Post</button>
</div>
```

Could Anyone help me out ??. YOu can also download and run the entire project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85vUqBPKLOxOVZ3d0pNVEJzNW8/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are registering the service as `webcallService`:

```
app.service('webcallService',  function() {
```

But inject the `$webcallService` in the controller:

```
app.register.controller('UserController', function ($scope, $location, $webcallService) {
```

Choose one, the one without `$` is recommend though, so declare your controller with `webcallService`:

```
app.register.controller('UserController', function ($scope, $location, webcallService) {
```

**EDIT:** Found one more problem, after reading the [angularAMD documentation](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD), it seems you have to add the requirejs module `WebCallManager` that contain the `webcallService` angularjs service as a dependency in `define()` as well.

Therefore, it should be like this:

```
define(['app', 'WebCallManager'], function (app) {
  app.register.controller('UserController', function ($scope,$location,webcallService) {
```

Otherwise, the module `WebCallManager` will not be loaded on-demand.

**EDIT:** Found the third problem, you register the controller via `app.register`, but register the service directly via `app.`. You need to be consistent here, but the `app.register` has been deprecated (See [this thread](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/pull/63)).

Therefore the best would be removing the `app.register` like this:

```
app.controller('UserController', ..
```

And in app.js change from:

```
angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
return app;
```

to

```
return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried both with and without the $ but still no luck. I have provided the source code for my seed project in the question. Could you please try it out and let me know ?.

Comment: It require a permission. I've already request for the permission, please accept it so I can download the source code.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Could you please try now ?.

Comment: Tried that...but still no luck :(. Did that work for you when you tried it with the source code provided ?.

Comment: Yes, it works, I mean the `Unknown provider: webcallServiceProvider` dissappeared.

Comment: Ah, I've edited something else during debugging, that why it works. I have updated the answer with the third problem found. Please try again.